# When using Perl to parse coordinates out of kmls how can I account for MultiGeometry polygons?

Tags: xml, perl, parsing, kml

I have written a perl script that extracts coordinates from some KML files. like this:

```
if ($start ne 6) 
  {
  $sheet = substr($line,$start,$end-$start);
  }
  $start =  index($line,"<coordinates>") + 13;
  $end = index($line,"</coordinates>");
  $coords = substr($line,$start,$end-$start); 
if ($start ne 12) 
  {
  @values = split (' ',$coords);
  foreach (@values) {}
  my (@lat, @long);
( $lat[@lat], $long[@long] )
    = split /,/ for @values;
```

this will extract coordinates from this line:  
    `<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-4.799999989183125,54.479999998144478 -5.399999989687073,54.479999998084068 -5.409999989614521,54.739999998345262 -4.809999989103597,54.749999998414239 -4.799999989183125,54.479999998144478</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>`

but when I have multiple ring polygons that repeat the `<LinearRing><coordinates>` tags many times in the one line it only retrieves the first set of coordinates (as you you expect).

So my question is this: is there a way that I can modify what I already have to accommodate multiploygons, or do I have to use a different parsing technique?

thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17231031/how-to-parse-kml-files-using-perl

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by replacing the index with a reverse index, then deleting anything between < and > :

```
while ( <INPUT> ) {
  chomp();
    $line = $_;
  $start =  index($line,"SHEET") + 7;
  $end = index($line,"</SimpleData>");
if ($start ne 6) 
  {
  $sheet = substr($line,$start,$end-$start);
  }
  $start =  index($line,"<coordinates>") + 13;
  $end = rindex($line,"</coordinates>");
  $coords = substr($line,$start,$end-$start);
  $coords =~ s/<.*>//; 
if ($start ne 12) 
  {

  @values = split (' ',$coords);
```